# Display:table expands the height of the div. Solutions?

Tags: css, html, displaytag

I have this `html` sequence that displays 2 bars. Because inside the first div I display an inline list, I want to use `display:table` because it looks nicer in this way. The problem is that it extends the div, making it bigger with 20px (and moves the other div lower).

```
<div class="top-bar></div>
<div class="tail-bar></div>

.top-bar{       
    width: 520px;
    height: 50px;
    dispaly: table;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
```

**EDIT**: I added a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eCYUT/2/

It is the version without `display:table` tag

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle of your code?

Comment: How does it "look nicer that way"? Instead of randomly changing CSS attributes and seeing which one looks best, you should set them to your needs. `display: table` and `display: block` serve different purposes.

Comment: I will setup a jsFiddle immediatly

Comment: give `.stats` class `margin: 0px;`/`margin-bottom: 0px;` property. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/eCYUT/3/).

Comment: Oh...It workds here but it didn't work in my page, probably it inherits something else.

Comment: @Setila In which browser and what is the version?

Comment: @Mr_Green Firefox 24. As I said, it works with your solution on JSFiddle but not in my page. I have to check why is not working. Anyway, thank you very much. Now I know the cause. You can post the answearto this question just to make this question answered.

Comment: Give your live link, then i can test it.

Comment: I fixed it also locally. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap between the `ul` element and the `div` element was actually the margin related to the `ul` element.

To remove it, give `margin-bottom: 0px` to the class name of the ul element.

```
ul.stats{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /* other css properties */
}
```